# SQL statement to find Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so I am fumbling here a bit.  I have the following table:

```
Entered             Generalist               Item
12/31/2012 07:26:50 Tom Smith                RTW/Updates
12/31/2012 07:30:10 Terrie Bradshaw          Posters
12/31/2012 07:38:16 Jen Lopez                Client Assistance/Request
12/31/2012 07:48:00 Tom Smith                RTW/Updates
12/31/2012 07:50:29 Mike Smith               RTW/Updates
12/31/2012 07:55:32 Tom Smith                Client Assistance/Request
```

I am trying to find out when was the last time a rep was assigned an item. So I am looking for the Min value on a column. My query would look at Item "RTW/Updates" when was the earlier time entered between a date range and return Tom Smith. For example the user queries, RTW/Update between 12/31/2012 and 1/1/2013 and the answer would be Tom Smith.

This is what I have so far, but have not been able to figure out the between the dates part:

```
    SELECT MIN(entered), generalist, item
FROM dataTable
```

That is pretty much it.

Comment: If you want the "last time", don't you want the max date?  And the answer in your case would be Mike Smith and not Tom Smith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work (where the @ variables are the parameters passed to your procedure)

```
SELECT MIN(entered), generalist, item
FROM dataTable
WHERE item = @itemParm
AND entered BETWEEN @enteredStart AND @enteredEnd
GROUP BY generalist, item
```

Answer (score 3):

I May not understand what you want, but if you want to get one person back based on the minimum date, you need to work out the minimum date, and use that to find that person:

```
select
*
from
datatable
where
entered = 
(
select
min(entered) as MinDate
from
DataTable
where
Item = 'RTW/Updates'
  )
and item = 'RTW/Updates'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50a20/2)

You could also use a CTE:

```
; with LowDate as
(select
min(entered) as MinDate
from
DataTable
where
Item = 'RTW/Updates' )

select
*
from
datatable
inner join LowDate
ON entered = LowDate.MinDate
and item = 'RTW/Updates'
```

[More SQL Fiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50a20/8)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the window functions.  Here is an example:

```
select generalist, item, entered
from (SELECT generalist, item, entered,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by entered desc) as seqnum
      FROM dataTable
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The function `row_number()` enumerates the rows for each item (based on the `partition by` clause) starting with `1`.  The row with `1` is going to have the most recent date, because of the `order by` clause.

The outer query just selects the rows where the `seqnum = 1` -- which is the most recent record for each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(entered) MinDate, generalist, item
FROM dataTable
GROUP BY generalist, item
```

When you have used an aggregate function in your select statement and you are also selecting other column which are not contained in any aggregate function you have to tell sql server how to aggregate that column by adding a GROUP BY clause and mentioning names of all the column that are in SELECT statement but not contained in any Aggregate function.

to get the latest Date you will need to get the Biggest(Largest in Number Date) and you will need to use MAX() function instead of MIN(), MIN() will return the Oldest (smallest Date) in your column.

```
SELECT MAX(entered) MinDate, generalist, item
FROM dataTable
GROUP BY generalist, item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY

```
SELECT MAX(entered) MinDate, generalist, item FROM dataTable
GROUP BY Generalist, Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something to the answers (which are correct, essentially) before this one : in order to find the latest date, you'll have to use `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`.